# Events order between DOM event and sencha event

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs7

I've a dataview, written with extjs 7.1 modern tookit, with a template with an *anchor tag* and a *select* event:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/34bd

```
Ext.create({
    renderTo: document.body,

    xtype: 'list',
    itemTpl: '<div class="contact"><a onclick="event.preventDefault();console.log(\'link\');" href="{firstName}">{firstName}</a> <b>{lastName}</b></div>',

    store: {

        data: [{
            firstName: 'Peter',
            lastName: 'Venkman'
        }, {
            firstName: 'Raymond',
            lastName: 'Stantz'
        }, {
            firstName: 'Egon',
            lastName: 'Spengler'
        }, {
            firstName: 'Winston',
            lastName: 'Zeddemore'
        }]
    },
    listeners: {
        select() { console.log('select'); }
    }
});
```

I expect the link event will be fired before the list select event, but the opposite happens and even worst both events will be fired one after another.

Comment: In your fiddle example, itemtap is Deprecated since version 6.5.0,  Use childtap. and about your expectations, why you cannot write your link logic in your childtap event?

Comment: I need to do different action if the user click on a specific link or in the whole list item.

Comment: I'm trying to understand where the user clicks as you suggest but I don't know how. You can see the code in sencha fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/34bd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to understand where the user clicks as you suggest but I don't know how.

As @LightNight said, you can use `childtap` event to run needed handler before select. If you want to understand where the click occurred - just use `event.target`. Look my [example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/34c7)

Answer (score 0):

how about onItemDisclosure property of list instead of a link?

use onItemDisclosure function and select listener to separate two actions.

> **onItemDisclosure** : Boolean / Function / String / Object BINDABLE
>
> Set to **true** to display a disclosure icon on each list item. The list will then fire the disclose event, and the event can be **stopped before childtap**. By setting this config to a function, the function passed will be called when the disclosure is tapped. This can be either a function object or the name of a Ext.app.ViewController method.
>
> Finally you can specify an object with a scope and handler property defined. This will also be bound to the tap event listener and is useful when you want to change the scope of the handler.

```
xtype: 'list',
itemTpl: [
    '<div class="contact">',
    '<b>',
    '{firstName} {lastName}',
    '</b>',
    '</div>'
],
onItemDisclosure: function (record, btn, index) {
    console.log('Disclosure');
    Ext.Msg.alert('Tap', 'Disclose more info for ' + record.get('firstName'), Ext.emptyFn);
},
store: {

    data: [{
        firstName: 'Peter',
        lastName: 'Venkman'
    }, {
        firstName: 'Raymond',
        lastName: 'Stantz'
    }, {
        firstName: 'Egon',
        lastName: 'Spengler'
    }, {
        firstName: 'Winston',
        lastName: 'Zeddemore'
    }]
},
listeners: {
        select() {
            console.log('select');
        }
}
```

here is [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/34bd) example

Comment: Good idea but my real data are a bit more comlplex. I updated the fiddle (https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/34bd) with your suggestion of using childtap instead of selected. In this event I've a reference to the clicked element so I can do the work.